# Deleting all files with some exceptions after installation with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

How can I delete a series of files once the `Run` has been executed?

I want to delete a lot of DLL files and some other files because they are now in separate sub folders. But some of the DLL files are registered COM etc. Once `Run` has finished the old DLLs will not be registered anymore. So it will be safe for me to delete them.

`InstallDelete` is too early:
https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=installorder

So I want ability to delete `*.dll` but exclude `pattern*.dll` ONCE install finished.

---

I've seen a similar question:

[Delete a file AFTER installation in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598242/delete-a-file-after-installation-in-innosetup)

It seems I need to use something like:

```pascal
[Code]
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then begin
    DeleteFile(ExpandConstant('path'));
    ..
```

Ideally I want to delete:

- `{app}\*.dll`
- `{app}\*.config`
- `{app}\GoogleAuthAndSync.exe`

But, I want to KEEP these files in the {app} folder:

- `{app}\MeetSchedAssist*.dll`
- `{app}\VclStylesinno.dll`

That is what I want to achieve. This is because the files are now being installed into distinct sub-folders and being managed there, and not all mixed up in the app folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CurStepChanged(ssPostInstall)` seems like the the right approach to me. So all you need on top of that is a way to delete all files, with some exceptions, right?

Start here:
[Delete whole application folder except for "data" subdirectory in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36491213/850848)

---

If you need to know how to test for partial filename (`MeetSchedAssist*.dll`):

- If you need just one-off test, an ad-hoc condition like this will do:

  ```pascal
  (CompareText(Copy(FindRec.Name, 1, 15), 'MeetSchedAssist') = 0) and
  (CompareText(Copy(FindRec.Name, Length(FindRec.Name) - 3, 4), '.dll') = 0)
  ```
- If you have many tests, you can use `MatchesMaskEx` function from [Inno Setup - Integer or Set/Range wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35052173/850848):

  ```pascal
  MatchesMaskEx('MeetSchedAssist*.dll', FindRec.Name)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would add my final code:

```pascal
(* Cannot use built-in DeleteFile directly in AfterInstall as it's a function,
    not a procedure. And this way we can add some error handling too. *)
procedure DoDeleteFile(FileName: string);
begin
    if (FileExists(FileName)) then
    begin
        if DeleteFile(FileName) then
        begin
            Log(Format('"%s" deleted', [FileName]));
        end
        else begin
            MsgBox(Format('Failed to delete "%s"', [FileName]), mbError, MB_OK);
        end;
    end;
end;

{ Deletes obsolete DLL files etc. }
procedure DelObsoleteFiles(Path: string);
var
    FindRec: TFindRec;
    FilePath: string;
begin
    if FindFirst(Path + '\*.dll', FindRec) then
    begin
        try
            repeat
                FilePath := Path + '\' + FindRec.Name;
                if CompareText(FindRec.Name, 'VclStylesinno.dll') = 0 then
                begin
                    Log(Format('Keeping DLL %s', [FilePath]));
                end else if CompareText(Copy(FindRec.Name, 1, 15), 'MeetSchedAssist') = 0 then 
                begin
                    Log(Format('Keeping DLL %s', [FilePath]));
                end else begin
                    DoDeleteFile(FilePath);
                end;
            until not FindNext(FindRec);
        finally
            FindClose(FindRec);
        end;
    end else
    begin
      Log(Format('Failed to list %s', [Path]));
    end;
  
    DoDeleteFile(Path + '\GoogleAuthAndSync.exe')
    DoDeleteFile(Path + '\GoogleAuthAndSync.exe.config')
  
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
    ResultCode: integer;
begin
    if (CurStep = ssPostInstall) then
    begin
        (* Delete obsolete DLL files etc. because they are now maintained in
          separate sub-folders *)
        DelObsoleteFiles(ExpandConstant('{app}'));
    end;
end;
```

Comment: I am puzzled by your comment in the code: "Cannot use built-in DeleteFile directly in AfterInstall as it's a function, not a procedure" - why do you say this? (It doesn't matter if `DeleteFile` is a function.)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart That is a comment carried forward from another answer provided to me here on SO over the years.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart See the answer here where the code provided has that comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48807033/2287576

Comment: Never mind; I confused myself. (An `AfterInstall` parameter isn't an event function and musn't have a return value per the docs.)